# Restore apps from backup on Google Drive

Tags: lineageos, 7.1-nougat, google-drive, google-backup

I have a backup of my old phone I can see in my Google Drive app on my new phone.

How do I backup/restore all the apps from this backup?

From searching, it looks like this should have been an option when first starting my phone but it wasn't.

Android version: 7.1.2

LineageOS version: 14.1

Answer (score 0):

You must reinstall the application for Google Backups to Automatically restore the application data and settings.

This information can be found on the Automatic Restore setting under settings > backup & reset

Here's a picture from the setting page's corresponding item:

[image: Imgur Picture]

Comment: That is certainly one way (and to my knowledge was the only one before Google decided on moving backups to Drive). But given the backup files were available on-device (if one can download them manually), would there be a way to restore them manually – e.g. by means of `adb shell` or a (root) terminal? I cannot tell as I'm not using Google's backup.

Comment: I just tried this but none of the apps I downloaded restored their settings.

Comment: I have never used this feature myself so it's just a hypothetical answer, usually if your device has changed from say Android 4.4 to Android 5.0 then the backup data will be incompatible due to certain storage scheme changes, As far as i know, google backup is more for Google to look at than you to use....  After doing a small amount of research, it seems that it should have asked you when setting up the device, here's the information i found on the whole process https://m.androidcentral.com/how-restore-your-apps-and-settings-new-android-phone