# Backup not listed to restore from on new Android device

Tags: restore, lineageos, oneplus-one, oneplus-3

I have 3 android devices synced to the same Google account:

- OnePlus One running Lineage OS 15.1 (up to date, not currently rooted)
- NVidia SHIELD Tablet K1
- OnePlus 3T - new, in factory reset state

I am trying to move all of my apps and data from the `One` to the `3T`. Google Drive on the `One` shows under "Backups" (text translated from Spanish w/best guesses from context, etc):

- Backup from A0001 - today at 21:49
- Backup from NVidia SHIELD Tablet K1 - today at 10:57

However, booting the `3T`, setting up the SIM, Wifi, and copying Google account information over using "Set up my device", entering account password, skipping "share my data" questions gets me eventually to the restore screen, which shows only the `K1` backup to restore from.

How can I fully restore from my `One` to the `3T`? I estimate reinstalling all of my apps (from 3 sources - Play store, F-Droid, and Humble Bundle) and getting data syncing working and synced for my personal data to take at least 5 hours, and would not include call data, chrome tabs, game saves, etc - so anything faster than that is fair game. I have set up `ADB` for my `One` and used it for file transfers a number of times, and can probably set it up for the 3T, so `ADB` is fair game.

Edit: currently open tabs on this issue (might save some time):

- [How to manually restore Call Log from adb backup on OnePlus One? (SMS already restored)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/115509/26373)
- [Why is my Android not restoring the app data from its Google Drive backup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/191320/26373)
- [Restore apps from backup on Google Drive](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/193819/26373)
- https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/get-all-your-data-onto-your-new-android-phone-0183525/ (most useful from google search results page 1 for various searches

Comment: See [adb tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adb) You will find a question by Izzy on how do it on an unrooted device

Comment: My `One` is pretty rootable - I just have to boot into TWRP and load the root package. I can also root the `3T` - just worried about passing SafetyNet afterwards - one Reddit thread commented that the 3T and other modern devices specially fail if the bootloader is even unlocked...

Comment: I wish it weren't - I play Pokemon Go with my wife, who cares less about privacy loss than I, and I care less about privacy loss than fun walks with her. I'll look into `adb backup` and restore - thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Posted as requested. You may please delete your comments as they have been incorporated

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing from comments ;

- OP has been unsuccessful in restoring from Google Drive trying the solutions linked in the question
- Using  [titanium-backup](/questions/tagged/titanium-backup) is not an option  as bootloader is unlocked on the old device but on the new device Safety Net would be tripped if unlocked and rooted, apart from wiping data
- Only option left is to take a back up as explained here (using `adb`} [How to fully backup non-rooted devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/131553). It has limitations so it's recommended to understand and test it out

Comment: Re your second bullet, I stated above that bootloader is _not_ locked on my old device, that I can root very easily on my old device, and there is no data on the new device. My only concern there is Safety Net on the _new_ device, should restoration require root, as to restore Safety Net on the new device would presumably wipe the device again.